# angular2 input text on enter key press is not working

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a form within it there is a text box which allow user to search something. Whenever I click enter after entering the text in input field angular is considering as form submit. How can I call a method on entering the text box. Please review the code below.

```
<form #f id="form-step1" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit($event)">
```

This form has its own validation part. So whenever I click the enter its taking to the validation part.

```
<input class="txt-box" type="text" name="map_address" 
[(ngModel)]="step1Data.map_address" value="" 
(keyup.enter) = "getAddress($event)" id="map_address" />
```

Comment: Have you tried with (blur) OR (change) event????

Comment: yeah.. its working.. but I want only on enter

Comment: It takes the address what given in input text and applying in google map

Comment: Have you tried `$event.stopPropagation()` in the `getAddress($event)` method?

Comment: @rajm Did the below answer your question?

Comment: @OliverCooke I think not, since OP wants it to work with enterkey :)

Comment: I have updated my answer, which should suit the question better if you want to take a look.